# Disable logging on third party dependency "SMBJ" using simplelogger

Tags: logging, slf4j, smbj

I am using com.hieronymous.smbj and try to disable the logging. The doc says, it uses sl4j so I tried a simplelogger.properties file in my resources

```
# App logging level:
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=OFF
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLog=OFF

# Disable SMBJ logging:
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log=OFF
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.com.hierynomus=OFF
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.com.hierynomus.smbj=OFF
```

I also tried to configure a logback.xml which looks like this

```
<configuration>
 <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
   <encoder>
     <pattern>
         %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t] --- %c{1}.%M:%L :: %m %n
     </pattern>
   </encoder>
 </appender>
 <root level="INFO">
   <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
 </root>
   <logger name="com.hierynomus.smbj" level="OFF"/>
   <logger name="com.hierynomus" level="OFF"/>
</configuration>
```

but there is no effect as well. Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

After removing this dependency in my .pom the log messages disappeared too

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```